# How can I detect the MSVC profiler running my code?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, profiler, msvc12

I'm looking for something akin to the Windows API `IsDebuggerPresent()` but to determine if the code is being profiled under MSVC2013. Does such an API exists, or is there another way?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Why would you need this ?

Comment: Better would be to pass a command line switch to the program to say "Go into alternate mode", rather than trying to detect alternate mode yourself. Auto-detection makes programs hard to debug.